# Payflow Pro Currency Configuration Issue

Tags: php, paypal

I am new to the Payflow Pro platform and have recently set up single and recurring transactions in the sandbox mode and they all work fine.

My issue is i am unable to configure the test payflow manager to accept and work with another currency other than USD. I need to be able to use GBP.

When I first authorize a transaction, i am sending currency code GBP. This shows up properly in the hosted checkout page.

After the transaction completes, when i go into payflow manager, the currency is USD, so everything paid into it turns into USD amounts.

I have asked this question to Payflow technical support but they are unable to provide me with information on what to do to change this.

Does anyone have any information on how this needs to be configured to accept another currency in the sandbox mode?

Comment: Are you getting any error while accepting the GBP?

Comment: no errors, it is just taking a GBP amount like 100.00 GBP (on hosted checkout page) and turning it into 100.00 USD after successful payment made.

Comment: Can you provide transaction id for any successful transaction ?

Comment: This is a PNREF from a recent test transaction: A10A7A95BE6F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when you have PayPal as the processor you can accept the multiple currency in the same Payflow account otherwise only one currency is accepted per Payflow account . You can check who is your processor by logging to the manager.paypal.com and then going to "Account Administration" --> "Processor Information" .

In case you want the processor to be changed , you need to contact the Payflow support .

Comment: Yes, in the payflow manager it says FDMS Nashville is my processor, which only accepts USD. I will contact payflow support and ask them to change to Paypal. Thanks for your help on this.